AWS Simple AD Directory - Computer not joined to a domain
Following the guidance from Directory Service Administration guide

I have created a new Simple AD Directory
Launched an Windows Server EC2 instance
Installed the Remote Server Administration Tools
Following the guidance from Manually join EC2 Windows to Simple AD
Updated the server DNS to point to my directory DNS IPs
Successfully joined the server to my directory domain

I'm trying to add my first user to the directory following the guidance from Create a Simple AD User.
When I launch Active Directory Administration Tools, I receive the following error message:
"Your account or computer is not joined to any domain. Join to a domain and try again."
Prior to joining the domain, I can add the prerequisite Server Features required for active directory user management. But after the domain membership, I am unable to view those features from the server features and roles window.
However, I am able to run the following command and see the required features are installed on my EC2 server:
Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "RSAT*"}

I'm at an impasse now trying to follow the directory administration guide to manage uesrs in my directory service. I don't see how I can RDP to the server using a domain administrator account without first being able to create my active directory users. And I've tried RDP connecting using the directory Administrator credential and password to no avail.
